# Is it possible to implement dynamic form input rows (adding new row by clicking on Add) with Handlebars and Meteor?

Tags: forms, dynamic, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm getting my hands dirty with Meteor, and I wanted to port this AngularJS app (http://simplydo.com/projector/) over as an exercise.

I'm having difficulty implementing adding dynamic input form rows to sections using Handlebars, and I've found no documentation anywhere that documents if this possible. It's a snap in Angular using **ng-repeat**, but I want to confirm if this is something that is possible in Handlebars or whether I need to use Jquery in order to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just as easy in Meteor

all you have to do is repeat the rows with `{{#each rowData}}` and have a button that adds a document to the collection. Here is an example:

In this template the rows for a page are shown. In order to add a row, the user has to click on the add image. The template is :

```
<template name="page">
   {{#with page}}
   <h3>{{title}}</h3>

   {{#each rows}}
   <div class="row-fluid page-row {{#if isSelected this}}selected-row{{/if}}">
         ... page content here
   </div>
   {{/each}}
   {{/with}}

   <div class="btn-toolbar">
      <div class="pull-right">
         <a id="add-row" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{lbl 'add-page'}}">
            <img src="/images/add.png" class="asset-icon"/>
         </a>

         <img src="/images/separator.png" class="asset-icon"/>

         <a id="delete-row" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{lbl 'delete-page'}}">
            <img src="/images/delete.png" class="asset-icon"/>
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

the helpers for this template are:

```
Template.page.page = function () {
   return Session.get("selected-page");
}
```

in order to add a page the `click` event for the add button is implemented:

```
   "click #add-row": function (evt, template) {
      var page = Session.get("selected-page");
      Pages.update({_id: page._id}, ... add a new row here ...)
   }
```

because the whole thing is reactive, the list of rows will redraw after the `update` on the `Pages` collection.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

One question. If I have to add a new sub-document representing a row to the Pages collection in this case in order to visualize a new row, does that not mean that its essentially initializing an empty document which remains empty until I choose to enter data in it?

Just want to make sure I understood this correctly.

Comment: this is exactly what happens. If you add an empty document, the list will be redrawn and the new (empty) document appended at the end (or beginning depending on sort order). But the row does not necessarily start empty, you can initialize it in the `update` or `insert`

Comment: Ok I think I get how to handle this now. Thanks for your help.